# New PowerShell as a user with administrator rights

Tags: powershell, administrator, user, runas

I want to open a new powershell.exe as a user but with the administrator rights (this user is already added to administrator group).

To open new powershell.exe as user, I used this command:

```
runas /profile /user:emma powershell.exe
```

Can I change it somehow to get what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "emma" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"
```

Assuming Emma is an admin.

Comment: @Karo936 if emma is already logged in, you can just `start powershell -verb runas`